# Adding Calculated Field to find percentage and Labeling each calculation %

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula, pivot-table

I would like to add below formula to my calculate field on the pivot table that will show the value to either "Yay" or "Nay" if the result is less than 5%

here is the formula =IFERROR(IF(AND(Orignial Qty<>0, (1-(Original Qty/Revised Qty))>0.05), "Yay", "Nay"), " - ")

here is the table

Month        Original Qty    Revised Qty

Jan     10.25              8.25

Feb     11.25   12.25

Mar 9.25    9.25

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You mentioned using a pivot table... Are the original and revised qty's calculated values based on sums by the  pivot table or is what you presented as the raw data or the result of the pivot?  I'm a bit confused.

Fundamentally I think you want to add a computed column to the results based on the grouping the pivot does.  I don't think you can directly do this.  You either have to add a formula based on the pivot, but then the formula is static and results don't change if you add filter/pivot data.

Comment: The Original and revised qty is based on Sums by the pivot table not raw data.. The revised qty is from a calculated field I added in to the pivot table. 

I want to add another calculated field in the pivot table that will give me the result of the =IFERROR(IF(AND(Orignial Qty<>0, (1-(Original Qty/Revised Qty))>0.05), "Yay", "Nay"), " - ")